# Startup FreeIPA with docker not working after install

Tags: docker, freeipa

I'm use these how to install the FreeIPA with Docker (centos7) [https://hub.docker.com/r/freeipa/freeipa-server/ ] and I do not see any errors after these command:

`

```
docker run --name freeipa-server-container -ti -h ipa.labs.net -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /tmp -v /var/lib/ipa-data/ipa:/data:Z freeipa-server:centos7 exit-on-finished --no-ntp


.............

The ipa-client-install command was successful

ipa         : ERROR    unable to resolve host name ipa.labs.net. to IP address, ipa-ca DNS record will be incomplete
ipa         : ERROR    unable to resolve host name ipa.labs.net. to IP address, ipa-ca DNS record will be incomplete
Please add records in this file to your DNS system: /tmp/ipa.system.records.iad5Ct.db
==============================================================================
Setup complete

Next steps:
        1. You must make sure these network ports are open:
                TCP Ports:
                  * 80, 443: HTTP/HTTPS
                  * 389, 636: LDAP/LDAPS
                  * 88, 464: kerberos
                UDP Ports:
                  * 88, 464: kerberos

        2. You can now obtain a kerberos ticket using the command: 'kinit admin'
           This ticket will allow you to use the IPA tools (e.g., ipa user-add)
           and the web user interface.
        3. Kerberos requires time synchronization between clients
           and servers for correct operation. You should consider enabling ntpd.

Be sure to back up the CA certificates stored in /root/cacert.p12
These files are required to create replicas. The password for these
files is the Directory Manager password
FreeIPA server does not run DNS server, skipping update-self-ip-address.
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/container-ipa.target.wants/ipa-server-update-self-ip-address.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/ipa-server-update-self-ip-address.service.
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/container-ipa.target.wants/ipa-server-upgrade.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/ipa-server-upgrade.service.
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/container-ipa.target.wants/ipa-server-configure-first.service.
FreeIPA server configured.
[root@labdocker freeipa-container]#`
```

But when start the container didn't work:

```
`[root@labdocker freeipa-container]# docker start -ai freeipa-server-container
[root@labdocker freeipa-container]# docker container ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7595dd26f073        freeipa-server:v0.2co   "/usr/local/sbin/ini…"   43 minutes ago      Up 20 seconds       freeipa-server-container
[root@labdocker freeipa-container]# docker container ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[root@labdocker freeipa-container]#`
```

I have no idea how to resolve this, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

> --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=0

to your docker run command.