# Error starting FreeIPA server as docker container

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, freeipa

I am getting error when I run the following command:

```
docker run --name freeipa-server-container -ti \
   -h ipa.example.test \
   --read-only \
   -v /var/lib/ipa-data:/data:Z freeipa-server [ opts ]
```

**ERROR:**

> systemd 239 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA
>   -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=legacy)
>
> Detected virtualization container-other.
>
> Detected architecture x86-64. Set hostname to `<ipa.example.test>`.
>
> Initializing machine ID from random generator.
>
> Couldn't move remaining
>   userspace processes, ignoring: Input/output error
>
> Sun Mar 22 16:47:43
>   UTC 2020 /usr/sbin/ipa-server-configure-first
>
> IPv6 stack is enabled
>   in the kernel but there is no interface that has ::1 address assigned.
>   Add ::1 address resolution to 'lo' interface. You might need to enable
>   IPv6 on the interface 'lo' in sysctl.conf. The ipa-server-install
>   command failed. See /var/log/ipaserver-install.log for more
>   information

Last part says I need to enable  enable IPv6 on the interface 'lo' in sysctl.conf.

Here is the output of `ifconfig`. It is already enabled. Isn't it?

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 661  bytes 56283 (56.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 661  bytes 56283 (56.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and also I couldn't find much about

```
Couldn't move remaining userspace processes, ignoring: Input/output error
```

Any pointers?? 
I am following this resource:  https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-container

Comment: Can you add your image's `Dockerfile` and any other source code needed to reproduce the issue to the question?  Systemd isn't really a great match for Docker, can you restructure the image to not need it?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, the Dockerfile I am using is provided by freeIPA and is there  in the above link. I  tried with `Dockerfile.fedora-31`  and  `Dockerfile.fedora-31` to build images. No issues with `docker build` command but `docker run` does not work.

Comment: https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-container/blob/master/Dockerfile.centos-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the same issue following [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746694/3896566), basically by adding `--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=0` into my `docker run ...` command. I don't actually know why it needs to be there but my symptoms were the same as yours and this did the trick. Here is my full command for testing:

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm \
    --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=0 
    --name freeipa-server-container \
    -h idm.example.test \
    -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    -v /var/lib/ipa-data:/data \
    --tmpfs /run \
    --tmpfs /tmp \
    freeipa/freeipa-server:latest
```

Sorry this isn't a great answer, but it might at least get you further down the road if you're still stuck.